# Java Permutation Recursion with helper method

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

I am getting an error on my homework assignment with the `permutationHelper` method.

The automated grading system called **zybooks** is not telling me what i am getting wrong..

However, it's giving me an error that says:

`Test feedback : permutation("123") incorrectly returned`
with my output showing:
`Your output : 123 132 213 231 312 321` 
which, imo looks exactly like its supposed to.

*(instructors left example in commented code)*.

I would very much like to understand why I am getting this error, even tho the code seems to be functioning properly. **Or** If there is a better way of accomplishing the task.

> **Note**
>
> > I am not allowed to change the parameters or headers of method.

Here is my code below.

```java
    /*
    * The following method is given to you, and you will be responsible for completing the permutationHelper method it calls.
    * Sometimes, helper methods are used for recursive methods when another parameter is needed to recursively call a method repeatedly, but passing that parameter initially doesn't make sense.
    */
    public static String permutation(String word){
        return permutationHelper(" ", word);
    }

    /* permutationHelper()
    * This method is called by the permutation method.
    * Given a string, return a string that lists all possible permutations of the letters in the string, with spaces preceding each permutation.
    * For example, "123" would give "123 132 213 231 312 321". 
    * The perm parameter keeps track of the current permutation you are creating.
    * Consider using the a for loop to call the method recursively a certain number of times with different parameters, so you cover all permutations.
    */
    public static String permutationHelper(String perm, String word) {
        if (word.isEmpty()) return perm;
        String a = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            a += permutationHelper(perm.trim() + word.charAt(i) + " ", word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i+1, word.length()));
        }
        return a;
    }
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked if you have any extra leading or trailing blank space?

Comment: @Juan is right, you have one space extra.  Because you are always appending " " to the parameter `perm` in your backtracker. So do a `trim()` on the result in `permutation` method.

Comment: I went and appended `trim()` to `permutationHelper(" ", word)`
like this:
`permutationHelper(" ",word).trim()`

and im still getting the errors.

(https://imgur.com/ciItPSM)
is a screenshot of the errors being returned.

Comment: The error was in the instructions, After bringing it up with the professors, they said to ignore the example in the commented code, and make sure that perm was preceding every iteration.
Thanks @Juan and others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    /*
* The following method is given to you, and you will be responsible for completing the permutationHelper method it calls.
* Sometimes, helper methods are used for recursive methods when another parameter is needed to recursively call a method repeatedly, but passing that parameter initially doesn't make sense.
*/
public static String permutation(String word){
    return permutationHelper(" ", word);
}

/* permutationHelper()
* This method is called by the permutation method.
* Given a string, return a string that lists all possible permutations of the letters in the string, with spaces preceding each permutation.
* For example, "123" would give "123 132 213 231 312 321". 
* The perm parameter keeps track of the current permutation you are creating.
* Consider using the a for loop to call the method recursively a certain number of times with different parameters, so you cover all permutations.
*/
public static String permutationHelper(String perm, String word) {
    if (word.isEmpty()) return perm;
    String a = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) a += permutationHelper(perm + word.charAt(i), word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i+1, word.length()));
    return a;
}
```

The error was in the Instructions.
Professors said to ignore the commented examples and make sure to have the perm precede the word.